# PouchDB can't convert blob into url for image src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pouchdb

Hey guys I'm working with PouchDB and react. File uploading is working normally but when I try to convert blob into url I'm having this error in console.

> "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution
> failed."

I checked the return and I'm able to retrieve all the data/images into the console and basically see the file types and so on.  Anyway I heard that "createObjectURL" is deprecated or so but I followed up the tutorial provided in docs for the PouchDB. So I'm not sure now. Can someone give me any insights or help on this ? Thanks

Snippet below:

```js
 // uploading files
    const uploadF = e => {
        // saving chosen file
        const file = e.target.files[0];

        // generating random number and converting it to the string
        const random_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        const random_id_to_string = String(random_id);

        console.log(file);

        // insert data into local DB
        db.post({
            _id: random_id_to_string,
            _attachments: {
                fileName: {
                    content_type: file.type,
                    data: file
                }
            }
        })

        // insert data into remote db
        redb.post({
            _id: random_id_to_string,
            _attachments: {
                fileName: {
                    content_type: file.type,
                    data: file
                }
            }
        })

        // upload file to s3 bucket
        S3FileUpload.uploadFile(e.target.files[0],config)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    // retrieve all data from db
    const files = [];
    db.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
        attachments: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(blob){
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(url);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    

    return(
        <section className="hero"> 
            <nav>
                <h2>Welcome</h2>
                <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                <input type="file" onChange={e => uploadF(e)} />
            </nav>
        </section>
    );
```

Comment: In the tutorial createObjectURL is being called on a blob, the results of a getAttachment(). In this example, it is being called on the js object representing everything allDocs found, which is not a blob. I think you need to examine what it returns and decide what blob to send (or move to an array of blobs) in your function that currently just returns its own input.

Comment: Yeah I found out it was not a blob but a base64 format.